# Cannot boot from USB on my Mac mini

Tags: osx-lion, bootable-media, mac-mini

Two weeks ago I installed OSX 10.8 on my Mac mini. After that, my system started to hang a lot, so I tried to erase it and install OSX 10.7 again. I used carbon Copy Cloner to make the bootable USB and it can load successfully on another Macbook. However, on my Mac mini, when I press on the option button to select the USB, it loads the white screen with a ban symbol at the center of the screen. After a moment, my machine automatically shuts down. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Edit: this is exactly the problem I have now http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1207168.html

**Update 1:** the hdd seems ok (from disk utility). I restored the booting partition by disk utility (drag the dmg file to that partition). After restarting and using that partition to boot, prohibited symbol is still there

**Update 2:** This is my disk utility [image]

I tried to erase the booting partition again and then, got the kernel panic (cpu 2 caller bla bla bla ). This is so ridiculus when I have a thing called "bootable" usb but cannot do anything to save the system. After the panic, my mac sounds 3 beeps in a row continuosly. I turned off the power after all.

Comment: so did u check if your disk is encrypted or not .. just like in the post you linked? And i wouldn't want to use a third party software to make a bootable USB when Disk Utility does it perfectly for me..

Comment: I erased the boot partition by using disk utility in the recovery mode and try to restore to that partition. Now I got the prohibited symbol everytime booting !!! Disk utility fails to create bootable usb for me all the time

Comment: It is wierd that Disk Utility gives you an error while creating a bootable USB. I suggest you re-download the `InstallESD.dmg` file from the AppStore, and try again with Disk Utility.

Comment: It turns out that prohibited symbol could be the results of several problems: hardware, software, even with norton anti vIrus http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100225150600825 . I will try with the installesd.dmg way to see there is any luck

Comment: 3 beeps usually means memory on PCs... Check out [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24847/how-do-i-check-my-macs-ram) on the Apple Stackexchange site